# Show that if $n$ divides $a^n-b^n$ then $n$ divides $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a,b,n \in \mathbb Z^+$. Show that if $n$ divides $a^n-b^n$ then $n$ divides $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$.

This is from Apostol’s *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Chapter $5$, exercise $13$.

It is trivial when $\gcd(n,a-b) = 1.$

It is also easy when $n$ divides $a-b$ since $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1-k} \equiv na^{n-1}\pmod n \equiv 0\pmod n$.

But after that, I am stuck. Any hint or help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $d=\gcd(n,a-b)$. The explicit expression
$$\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\ldots+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1},$$
shows that, because $a\equiv b\pmod{d}$, we also have
$$a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\ldots+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\equiv na^{n-1}\equiv0\pmod{d}.$$
That is to say $d$ divides $\tfrac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$.

Comment: I couldn’t see why this proves the result.

Comment: @OskarIngEnte If there is some part of the answer you do not understand, feel free to ask for clarification. Please do not vandalize the answer.

Comment: You have not proved that $n | \frac{a^n - b^n}{a - b}$.

Comment: @Laz Can you point out which part of the argument is lacking or unclear?

Comment: @Servaes The question was to prove that $n$ divides $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$, not that $d$ divides this number. You only proved that $d$ divides it.

Answer (score -1):

Proof:

When $n\in\mathbb{P}$:

1). $n\mid a$

$\Rightarrow n\mid b\Rightarrow n\mid\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

2). $n\nmid a\land n\nmid a-b$

$\Rightarrow n\mid\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

3). $n\nmid a\land n\mid a-b$

$d≔a-bn⇒a=b+nd$

$\because n\mid \binom{n}{i},\ 0<i<n$

$\therefore n\mid \binom{n}{1}b^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}b^{n-2}\left(nd\right)+\cdots+\left(nd\right)^{n-1}=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

When $n\notin\mathbb{P}$:

$\exists p_1,\cdots,p_s\in\mathbb{P}:n=p_1\cdots p_s$

$n_1≔p_2⋯p_s$

$\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=\frac{a^{n_1p_1}-b^{n_1p_1}}{a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}}\cdot\frac{a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}}{a-b}$

Based on the previously proven case where n is a prime number, we have

$p_1\mid\frac{a^{n_1p_1}-b^{n_1p_1}}{a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}}\Rightarrow\exists q_1\in\mathbb{N}^\ast:\ \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=p_1q_1\frac{a^{n_1}-b^{n_1}}{a-b}$

Repeat the above method,

$\exists q_2,\ \cdots,q_s\in\mathbb{N}^\ast:\ \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=p_1q_1\cdots p_sq_s=nq_1\cdots q_s$

$\therefore n\mid\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

Q. E. D.